# Insert elements into a list

Tags: python

I am a newbie trying to insert elements after the n:th element in the list. Any shorter/smarter ways?

```
def InsertElements(listName, var1, var2, n):

    listName.insert(n, var1)
    listName.insert(n+1, var2)
    return listName

myList = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "cherry", "grape"]

result = InsertElements(myList, "mango", "papaya", 3)
```

Comment: doesn't have .add(element) method ?

Comment: If you have a list of things to insert, you could do `newlist = list[:n] + added_elements + list[n:]`.

Comment: For some reason there is a "one line frenzy" going on in SO. I highly doubt that short code means good code. Anyway.. your code seems fine, excluding the return part which is somewhat redundant. `insert()` modifies your list so you can simply call your list after running your function without the need of a return inside it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many languages (e.g. JavaScript, Perl) have a `splice` function of some sort to modify list contents. They allow you to insert list items or change existing ones to new sublists.

Python uses a "slice" approach, allowing you to specify many list edits without a specific splice function.

```
>>> myList = ["banana", "orange", "apple", "cherry", "grape"]
>>> myList[3:3] = ["mango", "papaya"]
>>> myList
['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'mango', 'papaya', 'cherry', 'grape']
```

By the way, if this is hard to understand, this cheat sheet may help:

```
 ["banana", "orange", "apple", "cherry", "grape"]

  0_______  1_______  2______  3_______  4______ 5    # item index
  0:1_____  1:2_____  2:3____  3:4_____  4:5____      # equiv slice notation

  ^         ^         ^        ^         ^       ^    # slice notation for
  0:0       1:1       2:2      3:3       4:4     5:5  # 0_length positions
                                                      # between items

  0:2________________ 2:5_______________________      # misc longer slice 
            1:4_________________________              # examples
            1:5_________________________________
            1:__________________________________
  0:____________________________________________
  :_____________________________________________
  :3__________________________
  :1______
```

There are also negative indices (counting from the end of the list). Let's not get into those right now!

Comment: One thing I wish I'd explained a little better: When you ask a list for a single value (e.g. `mylist[3]`) you get back a single item. If you use the slice notation, you get back a list. Slices are also indexing, but they do not reduce the dimensionality of the result like integer indices do.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `.insert` will modify the list in-place, so after the call `result` and `myList` will refer to the same list.

Your code is OK. If you wanted a bit of a shorter option, you could use slicing:

```
listName[n:n] = [var1, var2]
```

This inserts both var1 and var2 after the nth item in the list.